# if else in a Wordpress function

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

I have the following code:

```
function wpb_hook_javascript() {
  if (is_page( array( 244, 174, 697, 702, 699, 708, 713 ) ) ) { 
    ?>
      <noscript>
            <iframe src="FORM_ONE" width="100%" height="550" type="text/html" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" style="border: 0"></iframe>
      </noscript>

      <script type="text/javascript">
            var form = 'FORM_ONE';
            var params = window.location.search;
            var thisScript = document.scripts[document.scripts.length - 1];
            var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');

            iframe.setAttribute('src', form + params);
            iframe.setAttribute('width', '100%');
            iframe.setAttribute('height', 550);
            iframe.setAttribute('type', 'text/html');
            iframe.setAttribute('frameborder', 0);
            iframe.setAttribute('allowTransparency', 'true');
            iframe.style.border = '0';

            thisScript.parentElement.replaceChild(iframe, thisScript);
      </script>
      
    <?php }

  elseif (is_page( array( 187, 283, 285, 287, 18608, 18619, 18629, 295, 297, 299, 303, 305, 307 ) ) ) { ?>
      <noscript>
            <iframe src="FORM_TWO" width="100%" height="550" type="text/html" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" style="border: 0"></iframe>
      </noscript>

      <script type="text/javascript">
            var form = 'FORM_TWO';
            var params = window.location.search;
            var thisScript = document.scripts[document.scripts.length - 1];
            var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');

            iframe.setAttribute('src', form + params);
            iframe.setAttribute('width', '100%');
            iframe.setAttribute('height', 550);
            iframe.setAttribute('type', 'text/html');
            iframe.setAttribute('frameborder', 0);
            iframe.setAttribute('allowTransparency', 'true');
            iframe.style.border = '0';

            thisScript.parentElement.replaceChild(iframe, thisScript);
      </script>
        
    <?php }

    else (is_page( array( 205, 399, 401, 403, 405, 407 ) ) ) {  ?>
      <noscript>
            <iframe src="FORM_THREE" width="100%" height="550" type="text/html" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" style="border: 0"></iframe>
      </noscript>

      <script type="text/javascript">
            var form = 'FORM_THREE';
            var params = window.location.search;
            var thisScript = document.scripts[document.scripts.length - 1];
            var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');

            iframe.setAttribute('src', form + params);
            iframe.setAttribute('width', '100%');
            iframe.setAttribute('height', 550);
            iframe.setAttribute('type', 'text/html');
            iframe.setAttribute('frameborder', 0);
            iframe.setAttribute('allowTransparency', 'true');
            iframe.style.border = '0';

            thisScript.parentElement.replaceChild(iframe, thisScript);
      </script>
    <?php }  

}
add_action('wp_head', 'wpb_hook_javascript');
```

Depending on the list of pages in the array I need to serve a different form. I currently have forms where I have FORM_ONE etc.  This code currently breaks my site.

If I delete the elseif & else it works BUT I have a lot more to add.

Can anyone please tell me what I've done wrong?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this condition:

```
else (is_page( array( 205, 399, 401, 403, 405, 407 ) ) ) {  ?>
```

Either change else to `elseif` or remove the condition after `else`

Comment: Seems to work, thank you. I thought the last one in a long if else statement had to be else.

Comment: No problem. There is no restriction for that, you can have as many `elseif` as you like without specifying the `else`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `endif;` on the bottom line.

If you want to use the `endif;` you have to use the following syntax:

```
<?php if ( condition ) : ?>

    { html goes here }

<?php elseif ( condition ): ?>

    { html goes here }

<?php else : ?>

    { html goes here }

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Ive removed it and still breaks the site:

Comment: Are you sure the error is in that snippet? What error message are you getting?